# @OnClick is not working in implementation of ButterKnife Library

Tags: android, butterknife

`@OnClick` is not working in implementation of ButterKnife Library

When I click on the `Button`, nothing is happening.

This is my full code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @InjectView(R.id.edit_user)
    EditText username;
    @InjectView(R.id.edit_pass)
    EditText password;

    @OnClick(R.id.btn)
    void submit() {
        // TODO call server...
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.inject(this);
        // TODO Use "injected" views...
    }
}
```

This is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_user"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="user" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_pass"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="user" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Thanks

Comment: did you call `ButterKnife.inject(this, view);` or `ButterKnife.inject(this);`?

Comment: ButterKnife.inject(this);

Comment: @shayanpourvatan have to change ButterKnife.inject(this) to ButterKnife.inject(this, view)??

Comment: you call this from `activity` or `fragment`?, if you call from activity `this` is enough but if you are in fragment or adapter you must pass your `view` too

Comment: I am using Activity, there is any requirement to enable annotations
?

Comment: post xml file and onCreate method please

Comment: @shayanpourvatan this is my code and just added butterknife-6.0.0 in project

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As mentioned in the Butterknife docs, If you are using Eclipse, you will need to [configure](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/ide-eclipse.html) the IDE before the annotations will be processed

Answer (score 11):

For anyone running into this issue in Android Studio, make sure you are including both of the necessary dependencies and the apt plugin in your respective build files (check the Butterknife readme). I rushed through the docs and only included the compile dependency, which caused binding to fail silently.

Comment: you can check out this link for more details: https://www.sitepoint.com/tidying-code-with-android-butterknife/

Answer (score 3):

In your activity try to add..

```
 ButterKnife.inject(this);
```

check this code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
ButterKnife.inject(this);
}

@OnClick(R.id.buttonAlert)
public void alertClicked(View v){
new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext())
    .setMessage(getFormattedMessge())
    .setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        }
    })
    .show();
 }
```

Comment: .inject has been changed .bind in the latest libraries

Answer (score 3):

Double check all dependencies in your project. Here is download instructions from readme file.
Configure your project-level build.gradle to include the 'android-apt' plugin:

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
      mavenCentral()
   }
   dependencies {
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
   }
}
```

Then, apply the 'android-apt' plugin in your module-level build.gradle and add the Butter Knife dependencies:

```
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

android {
  ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.2.1'
  apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.2.1'
}
```

Note: If you are using the new Jack compiler with version 2.2.0 or newer you do not need the 'android-apt' plugin and can instead replace apt with annotationProcessor when declaring the compiler dependency.

Answer (score 3):

Use `ButterKnife.bind(this);` in onCreate() of an Activity. or onCreateView for Fragment.

```
@OnClick(R.id.button_stop_sticky)
    public void onStopClicked(View v) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "onStop Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

And obviously, app module >  gradle add dependency

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Butter Knife you can bind your view like this also...

```
 class ExampleActivity extends Activity {

    @Bind(R.id.title)
    TextView title;
    @Bind(R.id.subtitle)
    TextView subtitle;
    @Bind(R.id.footer)
    TextView footer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.simple_activity);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        // TODO Use fields...
    }
}
```

for more details you can see this link http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/