# ButterKnife onclick is not working

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, onclick, butterknife

I injected views perfectly using butterknife library. But when I try to implement listeners, for example `onclick` I'm not able to implement them. Following java code will help you to understand my problem.

Java code:

```
public class LoginActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
    @InjectView(R.id.toolbar) Toolbar toolbar;
    @InjectView(R.id.btn_login) Button login;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        ButterKnife.inject(this);

        initialize();
        //initListeners();

        @OnClick(R.id.btn_login)
        public void submit(View view) {
          // TODO submit data to server...
        }
    }

    /*private void initListeners() {
        @OnClick(R.id.btn_login)
        public void login(){

        }
    }*/

    private void initialize() {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.toolbar_icon);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Tell me why it is happening. Anything wrong in code? I've already configured the IDE which is compatible with ButterKnife by using following URL.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754811/onclick-is-not-working-in-implementation-of-butterknife-library

Please give me any suggestions regarding this issue. Thanks in Advance..

Comment: can you post your stack Track

Comment: Put "submit" method outside oncreate

Comment: hi vinay it is giving "void is an invalid type for the variable submit"

Comment: hi piotr you can check it with butterknife github code.so that you can get more clarity on this..

Comment: This is the error which i am getting at compile time.please have look into it."Multiple markers at this line
 - void is an invalid type for the variable 
  submit
 - Syntax error on token ")", ; expected
 - Syntax error on token "(", ; expected"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.InjectView;
import butterknife.OnClick;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    @InjectView(R.id.button)
    Button login;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.inject(this);


    }


    @OnClick(R.id.button)
    void submitButton(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

and the activity_main.xml part

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="59dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="59dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="132dp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

in build.gradle file(app)

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
}
```

Comment: vinay i am not implementing android listeners.I need to do it with butterknife library..

Comment: but you have implemented normal android listener.i want to be implement listener with butterknife only.like following @OnClick(R.id.submit) void submit() {
    // TODO call server...
  }

Comment: Yes i have seen that see following url contains butterknife sample.i want listeners to be implement as it is..https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife

Comment: I still can use it even without "@OnClick" since it's linked using the xml: android:onClick="submitButton"

Comment: yes. It works without "@OnClick", as we are using in the xml file for button "android:onClick="submitButton""

Comment: but if you can use onClick() en the xml no it's necesary butterknife it's incorrect this answerd.

Comment: Ok i saw there was onClick implemented in XML as well, can't see it now. So that's why i said that because it doesn't make sense to implement onClick in XML and then implementing it through Butterknife as well. But still in this changed code you are comparing the view id, it isn't really necessary because you have already provided id to butterknife in annotation so it will take care of that, and only the associated view will receive the event.

Comment: this answer is missing { annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0' }

Answer (score 10):

In my case this is my solution

add **classpath** in gradle(*Project*)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    }
}
```

and gradle(*Module*) add **apply** and **apt**

```
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'   
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.2.1'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.2.1'
}
```

file java

```
@OnClick(R.id.btn_login)
public void submit(View view) {
  // TODO submit data to server...
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You should've to bind butterKnife before you use the annotations.

Add these dependencies to gradle.build

`compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'`

Then add bind to onCreate `ButterKnife.bind(this);`

Now do the code to Button. The method should be public and in butterKnife, you not required to add the onClick in XML. And method also should be outside of onCreate It'll automatically get button which you assign using the annotation given at above the method,

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

}
@OnClick(R.id.btn_login)
public void submit(View view){ 

   //Do your code here. 

}
```

Answer (score 4):

make sure you add all required dependencies

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
}
```

Comment: The OP mentions (in a comment) that he is getting compiler errors about different method signatures, not about missing dependencies.

Comment: no the Q about ButterKnife onclick is not working i have  face same issue and solved by adding missing dependency

Answer (score 2):

You have to move your `@OnClick` out of the `onCreate` method, as i did below in the code snippet.

The code i posted below should work as it's supposed to (I also use `ButterKnife`).

```
public class LoginActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
    @InjectView(R.id.toolbar) Toolbar toolbar;
    @InjectView(R.id.btn_login) Button login;

    @OnClick(R.id.btn_login)
    public void submit(View view) {
       // TODO submit data to server...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        ButterKnife.inject(this);

        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.toolbar_icon);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }
}
```